# javafx force image to be loaded

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to write a method to do something with the pixels in a `javafx.scene.image.Image`

```java
void process(Image image) {
 PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
 if (reader != null) {
 ...
 }
}
```

The [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) say " This method may also return null for some images in a format that is not supported for reading and writing pixels to." - this is fine, if there are no pixels then I don't need to do anything.

However it is also null if the Image is marked as being background-loaded and has not finished loading yet. Is there a way to force the image to be loaded?

I don't mind if there is a delay, or alternatively I don't mind setting up a listener to be called asynchronously.
Unfortunately `isBackgroundLoading` is just a method, not a JFX property so I can't attach a listener to it.

I have tried listeners on `error` and `progress` but can't get them to work or work reliably.

Using JavaFX 17 with JDK 17.

Comment: `backgroundLoading` is immutable; there is no point in adding a listener to it. What does not work with observing the `progress` property? Create and post a [mre].

Comment: Thanks James_D for the clarification. I interpreted the phrase "Indicates whether the image is being loaded in the background." to mean that when the image is no longer being loaded, it would be false.

Comment: *"Is there a way to force the image to be loaded?"* It's not entirely clear what you mean here (in what context do you want to force it to be loaded?) but you can explicitly force it to be loaded synchronously by setting `backgroundLoading` to `false` in one of the constructors (e.g. [`new Image(url, false)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,boolean))). The default value of `backgroundLoading` is `false` (though that is not well documented).

Comment: Still working on that minimal example... What I mean is - I want my `process(Image image)` to work even if someone passes in an image that has been constructed with backgroundLoading=true

Comment: The following idiom should work (assuming you are on the FX Application Thread): `if (image.getProgress() >= 1) { process(image); } else { image.progressProperty().addListener((obs, oldProgress, newProgress) -> { if (newProgress.doubleValue() >= 1) {process(image);}});}`. The `getPixelReader()` method (at least in the current implementation) returns null only if the progress is `<1`, or if an error occurred, or if the image is animated (e.g. an animated gif).

Comment: OK thanks James_D that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in the title ("How to force image to be loaded"), use an `Image` constructor which sets `backgroundLoading` to `false`. This is actually the default value, so either

```
new Image(url, false)
```

or, equivalently,

```
new Image(url)
```

will work.

To answer the question as described in the comments ("How to perform an action on an image when it is loaded, regardless of whether it is or was loaded in the background"), note that, at least in the current implementation, `Image.getPixelReader()` will only return null if

- the image is still being loaded (i.e. it is background loading and progress < 1), or
- there was an error loading the image, or
- the image is animated (e.g. was loaded from an animated gif).

If you only need to worry about the first possibility, i.e. you need to implement the following logic:

> If the image is loaded, process it, otherwise process it when it has been loaded

then the following idiom will work (as long as you are on the FX Application Thread):

```
public void processWhenReady(Image image, Consumer<Image> processingAction) {
    if (image.getProgress() >= 1) {
        processingAction.accept(image);
    } else {
        image.progressProperty().addListener((obs, oldProgress, newProgress) -> {
            if (newProgress.doubleValue() >= 1) {
                processingAction.accept(image);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(The point here is that the progress can only be updated on the FX Application Thread, and can only increase. So if it is already `>=1` it will never become `>=1` again; if it is not `>=1` the listener will be registered before it changes, by the single-threaded rule.)

Here is a quick and dirty example, using a deliberately large image loaded from the internet (so it takes a noticeable time to load). Note that loading synchronously (i.e. not in the background) will freeze the UI while it loads, but then by the time `getProgress()` is called it will return `1` (assuming no loading errors).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class MonitorImage extends Application {

    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/GSFC_20171208_Archive_e000053/GSFC_20171208_Archive_e000053~orig.png";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button loadAsync = new Button("Load asynchronously");
        Button loadSync = new Button("Load synchronously");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        loadAsync.setOnAction(e -> loadImage(imageView, true));
        loadSync.setOnAction(e -> loadImage(imageView, false));
        imageView.setFitWidth(800);
        imageView.setFitHeight(800);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        HBox controls = new HBox(5, loadAsync, loadSync);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(controls);
        root.setCenter(imageView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void loadImage(ImageView imageView, boolean background) {
        imageView.setImage(null);
        Image image = new Image(IMAGE_URL, background);
        // for debugging:
        image.progressProperty().addListener((obs, oldProgress, newProgress) -> System.out.println(newProgress));
        processWhenReady(image, this::process);
        imageView.setImage(image);
    }

    public void processWhenReady(Image image, Consumer<Image> processingAction) {
        if (image.getProgress() >= 1) {
            System.out.println("Image is ready: processing immediately");
            processingAction.accept(image);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Image is not ready: will process later");
            image.progressProperty().addListener((obs, oldProgress, newProgress) -> {
                if (newProgress.doubleValue() >= 1) {
                    processingAction.accept(image);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void process(Image image) {
        System.out.println("Processing image");
        PixelReader pixelReader = image.getPixelReader();
        if (pixelReader == null) {
            System.out.println("Null pixel reader");
            System.out.println("Loading error " + (image.isError() ? "occurred" : "did not occur"));
        } else {
            int centerX = (int)(image.getWidth() / 2) ;
            int centerY = (int)(image.getHeight() / 2) ;
            System.out.println("Color at center: "+pixelReader.getColor(centerX, centerY));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```